# How do I change permissions on data sources?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I'm migrating an SSRS installation from SQL Server 2005 to 2016. Last time I did this was I migrated it from SQL Server 2000 to 2005 and this is still the same `ReportingServices` databases.

I restored it on another server, set up a SSRS instance and going through all the active reports to check them.

This time I'm also deleting all data sources that are in folders or used by single reports and pointing reports to shared data sources.

My problem is that most of the time this is run by developers who develop, upload and set permissions for folders and reports and I've found that I cannot delete some data sources. I've pointed the reports to shared data sources but I want to get rid of these unused data sources.

I've added myself to the top level and lower level folder content manager role but still cannot do it

My worry is that developers will overwrite these reports with changes and upload them with a local data source or create new data sources again. In a DR situation I don't want change dozens of data sources.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add yourself as an Administrator role, you should be able to do whatever you want. Failing that, I can guarantee this will work:

You can go to your SSRS config tool to confirm the ReportServer Database location but it is probably located on your SQL Server in the ReportServer$INSTANCENAME database.

In there is a dbo.DataSource table which contains all of the Data Sources. You can look for the name of the Data Source you want to remove and drop that row from the table. Be careful that this also contains all Paginated embedded Data Sources so make sure you have the right one identified before you drop it.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid deleting rows from the RS database but might have to do that. Fairly sure that I added myself as administrator but there were a few data sources i could not delete or even view the properties of.

Comment: Click the gear at the top right and go to Site Settings. Then the security tab. You can see the different groups and roles there. There's only two roles, system user or Administrator. Make sure you're in an admin group.

Comment: You can also check in the actual datasource under manage and then the security tab. Under there you can see who has Content Manager permissions. You might just need to add your current group here.